# iOS Facebook Live video with RTMP + LFLiveKit

Tags: ios, facebook, video-streaming, live, rtmp

I have develop Facebook live video option from assets video through `LFLiveSession.pushVideo(BufferFrame)` but at the end live videos are appear very blurry.

So i update session to use `H264` Encoding what Facebook require. Also followed other Facebook live video stream rules, live 30fps, key frame in 2 sec, 4mbps max bit rate etc. Also tried diff videos with diff bitrate and fps.

Since i am using `H246` encoder the quality is bit improved but it's not 100%, still lots of noice in the video.

NOTE: I am live from assets video with pushing pixel buffer to RTMP session.

Any help would appreciate.

Thanks!

[image]

Code Edit 2:

```
var session: LFLiveSession = {
        let audioConfiguration = LFLiveAudioConfiguration.defaultConfiguration(for: LFLiveAudioQuality.high)
        let videoConfiguration = LFLiveVideoConfiguration.defaultConfiguration(for: LFLiveVideoQuality.high3, outputImageOrientation: .landscapeLeft)
        let session = LFLiveSession(audioConfiguration: audioConfiguration, videoConfiguration: videoConfiguration, captureType: LFLiveCaptureTypeMask.captureDefaultMask)

        return session!
    }()

func displayLinkDidRefresh(link: CADisplayLink) {
    let itemTime = videoOutput.itemTime(forHostTime: CACurrentMediaTime())

    if videoOutput.hasNewPixelBuffer(forItemTime: itemTime) {
        if let pixelBuffer = videoOutput.copyPixelBuffer(forItemTime: itemTime, itemTimeForDisplay: nil){
            self.session.pushVideo(pixelBuffer)
        }
    }
}
session.startLive(stream)
```

Video via Input mask, Audio via mic

```
LFLiveCaptureDefaultMask = (LFLiveCaptureMaskAudio | LFLiveInputMaskVideo)
```

Configuration:

```
case LFLiveVideoQuality_High3:{
    configuration.sessionPreset = LFCaptureSessionPreset720x1280;
    configuration.videoFrameRate = 30;
    configuration.videoMaxFrameRate = 30;
    configuration.videoMinFrameRate = 15;
    configuration.videoBitRate = 1200 * 1000;
    configuration.videoMaxBitRate = 1440 * 1000;
    configuration.videoMinBitRate = 500 * 1000;
    configuration.videoSize = CGSizeMake(720, 1280);
}
```

Edit 3:

> ```
>     let stream = LFLiveStreamInfo()
>     stream.url = fbLive.url!
>     print("rtmp :\(fbLive.url!)")
>     session.startLive(stream)
> ```

Comment: There are about a million that could be wrong. Its impossible to help without seeing code.

Comment: @szatmary updated question with my code, please help if it is make sense.

Comment: what is your upload speed in mbit/sec?

Comment: configuration.videoBitRate = 1200 * 1000; it's bit/sec

Comment: @szatmary updated question with configuration edit, thanks for your replay :)

Comment: @OlgaKhylkouskaya update question with configuration edit, thanks for your replay :)

Comment: @Ajit thank you for the configuration details. I also needed your internet speed. From the device you trying to stream please open any speed test service, for example: http://beta.speedtest.net/ Or any other. It will show your speed in Mbps: http://www.attinternetservice.com/resources/mbps-vs-mbps/ Then divide it to 8 and you get upload speed in mbit. Based on your configuration you need at least 1.2-1.5mbit

Comment: @OlgaKhylkouskaya Thanks for your suggestion. I'll definitely go through speed. Thanks again!

Comment: @AJit Have you solved this issue? Can you please share full code?

Comment: @TheTiger probably the problem i see is my internet speed, because code working fine with my colleague in another country with great internet speed.

Comment: @AJit You didn't show the code where you defined the stream object. Can you add that snippet too?

Comment: @TheTiger updated snippet with Edit 3, you need to call start session before pushing pixelBuffers.